# Find the area between the graph $y=e^{-x}\sin x, x \geq 0$ and the $x$-axis. Calculate the area of ​the area.

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

Find the area between the graph $y=e^{-x}\sin x, x \geq 0$ and the $x$-axis.  Calculate the area of ​​the area.

answer：[image]

The part of the red line is marked out, how do you think of it? If you don’t read the answer, what do you do? I can’t think of this answer. I don’t understand it. It may be that I lack some knowledge and ask God to give pointers on background and facts.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It is just simple addition. Think of the area between |sin(x)| and x-axis from x = a to x = b, you gotta do that.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ok, I will read it later.

Comment: @AjayMishra Thank you again,

Comment: @AjayMishra I understand this answer, this is Riemann.  Learn from you

Answer (score 3):

They have calculated
$$J_k:=\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}e^{-x}|\sin x|\>dx$$
for even and odd $k$ separately, and have obtained
$$J_k={1\over2}e^{-k\pi}(1+e^{-\pi})$$
in both cases. It follows that
$$S=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}|\sin x|\>dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty J_k={1\over2}(1+e^{-\pi})\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k\pi}={1\over2}\,{1+e^{-\pi}\over 1-e^{-\pi}}\ .$$